# TextInput I am try to add text in variable on onChangeText event in ReactNative

Tags: react-native

I have created to textInput field, and I have created two variable email and password.I am trying to enter text in a variable but it shows me undefined data in the alert. Please help. I am try to use email and password validation.

```
  state = {
            email: '',
            password: ''
         }

         handleEmail = (text) => {
            this.setState({ email: text })
         }
         handlePassword = (text) => {
            this.setState({ password: text })
         }
         fn_showalert = (email, pass) => {

          alert('email: ' + email + ' password: ' + pass)
       }

        render() {
            return (
                <ImageBackground style={styles.backgroundContainer} source={require('../assets/stars.jpg')} >

                <View style={{  alignItems: 'center',width:'100%' }}>

                <Text>Home Screen</Text>    
                    <TextInput style = {styles.input}
                   underlineColorAndroid = "transparent"
                   placeholder = "Email"
                   placeholderTextColor = "#9a73ef"
                   autoCapitalize = "none"
                   color = "#ffffff"
                   onChangeText = {this.handleEmail}/>

                <TextInput style = {styles.input}
                   underlineColorAndroid = "transparent"
                   placeholder = "Password"
                   placeholderTextColor = "#9a73ef"
                   autoCapitalize = "none"
                   color = "#ffffff"
                   onChangeText = {this.handlePassword}/>

                    <Button
                        title="Go to Details"
                        // onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Second', {
                        //     name: 'John',
                        //     age: 12,
                        // })}
                         onPress={this.gotoSecondButton}
                    />
                </View>
                </ImageBackground>
            );
        }
    } 

 gotoSecondButton() {
        this.fn_showalert()
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Where do you call the fn_showalert function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the following changes

```
fn_showalert = () => {
    const { email, pass } = this.state;
    alert('email: ' + email + ' password: ' + pass)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `TextInput`s, you never actually set the text the user entered into state.

You need to pass the text to `OnChangeText`

```
<TextInput
    OnChangeText = { (text) => this.handleText(text) }
/>
```

And then you can write your `handleText` function.

```
this.state = {
    text: ""
}
handleText = (text) => {
    this.setState({text: text})
}
```

Also, you shouldn't be writing your functions in your state. That doesn't really make sense. Please put them outside.